# count classes and assign different id

Tags: jquery

I have three elements with the same class:

```
<div class="hotel_price">30.00</div>
<div class="hotel_price">35.00</div>
<div class="hotel_price">36.00</div>
```

my function:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){ $('.hotel_price').attr('id','hotel_'+i);}
  });
</script>
```

the result:

```
<div id="hotel_3" class="hotel_price">30.00</div>
<div id="hotel_3" class="hotel_price">35.00</div>
<div id="hotel_3" class="hotel_price">36.00</div>
```

and I need:

```
 <div id="hotel_1" class="hotel_price">30.00</div>
    <div id="hotel_2" class="hotel_price">35.00</div>
    <div id="hotel_3" class="hotel_price">36.00</div>
```

Comment: your other question got closed, so i'll answer you here. Your problem was that you had converted you "string" to an "integer", thus you could not use "substring" on it. I have a working "correct" example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/6tYwC/) that also uses less code. Simply include that function, then where you want to apply it to something, assign the func to a variable and get the substrings you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
$('.hotel_price').attr('id', function(i) { return 'hotel_' + i; });
```

The reason your code is not working is because you are setting the IDs of all 3 elements each time through the loop:

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {
   // at this point, there is nothing specifying which .hotel_price to modify
   // so all 3 of them will be changed each time around
   // using .attr(name, fn) or .each(fn) is the jQuery way to do this.
   $('.hotel_price').attr('id','hotel_'+i);
}
```

Comment: This is much better than using `each`

Comment: Minor quibble, perhaps, but wouldn't `prop()` (for the `id` property) be a better choice?

Comment: @DavidThomas, is `id` a property?  I would have thought in this instance `.attr()` is ok.

Comment: +1 - I've never seen a function used in this situation, very handy!  Index specifier and all.

Comment: David Thomas every time I see the prop vs. attr arg I think negligible. they both work and if on older ver of jquery? when u have guys new to dev who knows what ver they have.

Comment: @Derek (and implicitly C.Hazelton): I'm not quite sure, I've read a number of arguments either way on the matter and my own use of `prop()` to set/get the `id` (in those situations where for some reason I can't use `nodeRef.id`/`nodeRef.id = ...`) is probably habitual more than rationalised.

Comment: @C.Hazelton New devs drop their own version of jQuery into your site?  That's a bit agro don't you think?

Comment: For consistency, .prop() should be used as it is internally using elem.id instead of setting attribute on DOM element

Comment: `prop` is normally used for temporary states like enabled/disabled, clicked/unclicked. `attr` is used to set attributes in the DOM: id, class, href, src.

Comment: I normally prefer to use `.prop()`, but I would have thought `.attr()` is the preferred choice for ID.  However, I admit to not being 100% clear on when something is a property versus an attribute.  I would love to see a resource that explained this in really simply, hard-to-get-wrong terms!

Comment: @DavidThomas: jQuery has an example on the .attr() page doing exactly what I am doing above: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#example-1-1

Comment: @Barmar, thx, I've seen that post several times.  Yet somehow we're not clear.  I would have thought ID was an attribute, but now there's an argument that it's a property.  Or is it both?

Comment: @DerekHenderson: The 1.6.1 Release Notes has a nice table showing what is what: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/ - ID is an attribute.

Comment: Did the OP want id's to be 1,2,3 and not 0,1,2?

Comment: @PaoloBergantino, thank you, that will prove to be a very useful resource!

Comment: @Ascherer: He can take it from here ;) I would imagine in most cases it wouldn't really make a difference (and I strongly suspect he probably doesn't even need to do this), but my goal is not for my answer to be copy+paste ready.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino fair enough haha. There was a pending edit for it, so i thought id make a comment

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `each()` function to iterate over the elements.

```
$('.hotel_price').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'hotel_' + i);
});
```

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, though the approach suggested by @PauloBergantino is nicer still.

Comment: I agree. It was so simple and handy. I actually learnt something from it. :D

Comment: Ditto.  +1 anyway, because there's nothing at all wrong with this approach.  I edited your answer to remove the `$(document).ready()` part, since it's implied (and op is already using it) -- just to make the charcter-lenth of your answer similar to the popular answer.  I think the only very minor drawback to this approach is the 2nd `$(...)` call required.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija (and implicitly Madbreaks): I wanted to give a +1 to this answer, but I am surprised how both of you missed a major thing here... **selector missing quotes**!

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$('.hotel_price').attr(...)` you're setting the attribute of all elements that match the selector. You need to iterate over the elements, operating on each of them in turn so you can assign different attributes to each. jQuery's `each()` method is used for this.

```
var i = 1;
$('.hotel_price').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id','hotel_'+i);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: No need for an external var like that, use the index passed to `each`

Comment: I could, but they start from 0, so I'd have to add 1 to it. No big deal either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.hotel_price').each(function (ctr) {
         $(this).attr('id', 'hotel_' + (ctr +1));
     });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery's [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){ $('.hotel_price').eq(i-1).attr('id','hotel_'+i); }
});
```